# Pasar objetos entre componentes usando useNavigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

necesito una forma de pasar información de un estado a otro usando el hook useNavigation de esta manera:

```
navigate = useNavigate()

navigate("/App", {                                                  
state: res.data.usuario,
});
```

Pero al momento de hacer la redirecion al componente me sale un error en consola:

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

como haría para pasar un objeto de un componente A a un componente B?

Esta es la manera como tomo los datos del formulario y la llamada a la api:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState("");
const [pass, setPass] = useState("");
const navigate = useNavigate();

const loguearse = async () => {
    try {
        const response = Axios.post("http://localhost:8080/auth/login", {
            email: user,
            password: pass,
        });
        return await response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("NO SE PUDO INCIAR SESION");
    }
};
```

Esta es lo que retorna la api:

```
{ "mesagge": "Sesion iniciada correctamente",
  "token": "",
  "user": {
        "_id": "",
        "classification": "",
        "name": "",
        "lastname": "",
        "email": "",
        "password": "",
        "balance": ,
        "tokenVersion": 0,
        "cars": [
            {
                "plate": "",
                "gas": 0,
                "_id": ""
            }
        ],
        "transactions": [],
        "__v": 1
    }
}
```

Quiero poder transmitir el token y el usuario desde el componente donde hice la llamada hacia otro, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: que estás usando para hacer el Navigation?, falta información para poder ayudarte, favor subir código del componente completo o lo importante para verificar siempre que estás importando, como lo estás aplicando. Explicar que estás usando, ej: react-router, react-navigation, no olvides que hay muchas herramientas que usan la misma sintaxis. Es más sencillo para los usuarios ayudarte sabiendo que camino tomar. Supongo que eso explica que aun no tengas respuestas.

Comment: Gracias, sime dí cuenta que no proveí mucha información, ya edite la pregunta para hacer mas claro el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tendrías que hacer es primero que nada el useNavigate usarlo del lado de React o sea lado cliente, donde no tenés un res, res y req los tenemos en servidor en general, o no lo veo en el ejemplo que pasaste, básicamente deberías hacer la llamada y entonces podrías hacer algo así:

```
    const loguearse = async () => {
        try {
            // Agrego el await antes del Axios
            const response = await Axios.post("http://localhost:8080/auth/login", {
                email: user,
                password: pass,
            });
             //Asegurate si viene en response o response.data y usa el correspondiente, axios generalmente tiene .data
            if(response.data.token){
              navigate('/App', { state: {userData: response} });
              // o este otro
              navigate('/App', { state: {userData: response.data} });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("NO SE PUDO INCIAR SESION");
        }
    };
```

Finalmente en el componente de destino podrías hacer algo así para probar si llegó el objeto, ojo con pasar el objeto completo, porque también llegaría el password, etc, eso lo podés limitar de muchas maneras, pero lo ideal sería hacerlo del back antes de retornarlo.
Debes importar el hook useLocation()

```
const { state } = useLocation();
console.log(state.userData);
```

Espero te sirva, sino necesitaré más info de componentes y ver como lo tenés armado para ayudarte. Quedo a las órdenes.

---

Te dejo de todos modos un ejemplo aplicado en 2 componentes de prueba.

Componente2 Tiene un botón y un objeto de prueba, al presionar botón redirecciona a Componente1 que recibe los datos del objeto.

Entonces quedaría así:

Component2 (Envía el objeto)

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Component2() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  //Este es un objeto de prueba, en tu caso sería la respuesta de Axios.
  const obj = {
    Nombre: "Luis",
    Apellido: "Perez",
    Edad: 35,
  };

  function handleClick() {
    navigate("/", { state: { userData: obj } });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Componente 2</h1>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Ir a Componente 1 pasando objeto
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Component2;
```

Component1 (recibe el objeto):

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function Component1() {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Componente 1 Mostrando Datos del objeto recibido</h1>
      {state ? (
        <ul>
          <li>Nombre: {state.userData.Nombre}</li>
          <li>Apellido: {state.userData.Apellido}</li>
          <li>Edad: {state.userData.Edad}</li>
        </ul>
      ) : (
        <p>No ha recibido nada aún</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Component1;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! sirvió  la solución,

Comment: Justo estaba agregando un ejemplo que agregué al final de la respuesta, no había tenido tiempo para armarlo, me alegro que funcionara, quedo a las órdenes.